# Why is ASP.NET core reactjs app not working in IIS?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, iis, webpack

I published the reactjs asp.net core app with .net core 2.2.

And then i created a website in IIS under the main website folder, pointing to the published folder with an un-managed app pool.

When i browse to the website, i am getting a white-screen. If I check in chrome inspector,  I see the following warnings
[image: warnings]

webpack.config.js content:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

const useExperimentalFeatures =
    process.env.CARBON_USE_EXPERIMENTAL_FEATURES === 'true';

const useBreakingChanges = process.env.CARBON_USE_BREAKING_CHANGES === 'true';

const useExternalCss =
    process.env.CARBON_REACT_STORYBOOK_USE_EXTERNAL_CSS === 'true';

const useStyleSourceMap =
    process.env.CARBON_REACT_STORYBOOK_USE_STYLE_SOURCEMAP === 'true';

const replaceTable = {
    componentsX: true,
    breakingChangesX: true,
};

const styleLoaders = [
    {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
            importLoaders: 2,
            sourceMap: useStyleSourceMap,
        },
    },
    {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
            plugins: () => [
                require('autoprefixer')({
                    browsers: ['last 1 version', 'ie >= 11'],
                }),
            ],
            sourceMap: useStyleSourceMap,
        },
    },
    {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {
            includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules')],
            data: `
        $feature-flags: (
          components-x: ${useExperimentalFeatures},
          breaking-changes-x: ${useBreakingChanges},
          grid: ${useExperimentalFeatures},
          ui-shell: true,
        );
      `,
            sourceMap: useStyleSourceMap,
        },
    },
];

module.exports = (baseConfig, env, defaultConfig) => {
    defaultConfig.devtool = useStyleSourceMap ? 'source-map' : '';
    defaultConfig.optimization = {
        ...defaultConfig.optimization,
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                sourceMap: true,
                terserOptions: {
                    mangle: false,
                },
            }),
        ],
    };

    defaultConfig.module.rules.push({
        test: /(\/|\\)FeatureFlags\.js$/,
        loader: 'string-replace-loader',
        options: {
            multiple: Object.keys(replaceTable).map(key => ({
                search: `export\\s+const\\s+${key}\\s*=\\s*false`,
                replace: `export const ${key} = ${replaceTable[key]}`,
                flags: 'i',
            })),
        },
    });

    defaultConfig.module.rules.push({
        test: /-story\.jsx?$/,
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: require.resolve('@storybook/addon-storysource/loader'),
                options: {
                    prettierConfig: {
                        parser: 'babylon',
                        printWidth: 80,
                        tabWidth: 2,
                        bracketSpacing: true,
                        trailingComma: 'es5',
                        singleQuote: true,
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
        enforce: 'pre',
    });

    defaultConfig.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.scss$/,
        sideEffects: true,
        use: [
            { loader: useExternalCss ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : 'style-loader' },
            ...styleLoaders,
        ],
    });

    if (useExternalCss) {
        defaultConfig.plugins.push(
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: '[name].[contenthash].css',
            })
        );
    }

    return defaultConfig;
};
```

Comment: can you post full stack trace, also your webpack config if any

Comment: @rikin please take a look

Comment: you seem to have config related issue, notice first error message in Dev console, it says none of the production config found so most likely it never compiled anything